# Eu consigo colocar um WHERE para cada coluna?

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

Estou querendo colocar uma condição para cada coluna no meu SELECT, isso é possível?

```
SELECT count(id_casa) as casaAzul, count(id_casa) as casaAmarela FROM tb_casa
```

Onde: 
Where coluna 1: where cor_casa = 'azul'
Where coluna 2: where cor_casa = 'amarela'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma opção para fazer esta contagem é:

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE cor_casa = 'azul' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS casaAzul,
    SUM(CASE cor_casa = 'amarela' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS casaAmarela
FROM tb_casa;
```

Answer (score 2):

Você está contando duas vezes a mesma coluna (id_casa) e chamando uma de casaAzul e outra de casaAmarela. O que você deve fazer é agrupar as casas pela cor e dar um count nela.

MySQL mexi muito pouco, não lembro como ficaria o comando.. Abaixo segue em Oracle para você se basear (deve ser bem parecido, faça testes e pesquise no google as possíveis alterações).

```
SELECT COR_CASA as COR, COUNT(*) as QUANTIDADE
  FROM TB_CASA
 WHERE COR_CASA IN ('azul', 'amarela')
 GROUP BY COR_CASA
```

Comment: Então, e se eu quiser contar as casas que tem o numero maior que 500 e menor que 500 ?
Uso o in(n_casa > 500, n_casa < 500) ?

Comment: Pode sim. Mas você quer botar as duas cláusulas no mesmo select? Pergunto porque se você botar < 500 e > 500, virão todos os números menos o 500. Então seria mais simples você colocar uma cláusula só dizendo n_casa diferente de 500 (no Oracle é o simbolo de diferente é <>, no MySQL deve ser esse ou !=).

Agora, caso você queira fazer separadamente, basta incluir uma cláusula 

   AND N_CASA > 500

e depois fazer outro select com 

  AND N_CASA < 500

Comment: Na verdade, isso foi só um exemplo, o problema real é que: Tenho um lista de caminhões, onde classifico se são leves ou pesados a partir de um calculo.

Quero separar a quantidade dos pesados e a quantidade dos outros agrupado por data.
RESULTADO:
|      Date      | Pesados | Outros |
| 10/04/2014 |     121     |    45     |
| 11/04/2014 |     355     |     121   |
.
.
.

Comment: Só um adendo:
O comando "in" funciona como um OR. Neste seu exemplo você poderia colocar:

Where COR_CASA in ('azul', 'amarela')  ou  Where COR_CASA = 'azul' OR COR_CASA = 'amarela'. Ambos são equivalentes. Esse seu filtro n_casa > 500 vai com uma cláusula AND porque você quer que as casas sejam azul/amarela E que o número seja maior que 500.

Comment: Entendi sua dúvida.. nesse caso você vai ter que agrupar por data e pelo tipo do caminhão. Essas informações de data e tipo do caminhão estão numa tabela só? Qual é o nome da tabela e o nome dessas colunas?

Comment: Estão em uma tabela, 
a tabela se chama tb_vbv, 
eu defino se são pesados ou não por uma coluna que se chama gross, onde são pesados se gross > 12600 e outros se gross < 12600

Comment: Entendi.. qual o nome da coluna da data que você precisa mostrar ?

Comment: O nome da coluna é date

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83812/discussion-between-marcelobambino-and-leandro-kojima).

Answer (score 1):

Conseguimos resolver!

Segue o codigo SQL:

```
SELECT DATE(DATE) AS DATA, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM TB_VBV T 
WHERE DATE(T.DATE) = DATE(T1.DATE) 
AND GROSS > 12600 ) as QUANTIDADE_PESADOS, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM TB_VBV T 
WHERE DATE(T.DATE) = DATE(T1.DATE) 
AND GROSS < 12600 ) as QUANTIDADE_OUTROS 
FROM TB_VBV as T1
GROUP BY DATA 
ORDER BY DATA
```

Answer (score 0):

Sim, é só usar os operadores lógicos do SQL, como por exemplo AND, exemplo:

```
SELECT nm_casa, count(id_casa) FROM tb_casa
WHERE nm_casa = 'minhacondição' AND id_casa = 'minhacondição'
```

[Mais sobre operadores lógicos em sql.](https://www.devmedia.com.br/clausula-where-e-seus-operadores-no-sql/17291)

Comment: E se ele precisar que seja OR?

Comment: Eu me confundi na pergunta, mas não quis dizer isso, vou editar ela.